# Difference of induction and divide and conquer

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, induction, problem-solving, puzzle

I have seen that induction and divide and conquer are used as problem solving techniques but they are treated either as something different or the former as a way to support the latter.

To me it seems that they are both exactly the same thing i.e. defining the problem in a way that has (can be composed of) smaller instances of the same original problem, having a base case and a way to build a solution for instance $n  + 1$ having the solution to instance $n$.
So in my understanding they (induction and divide and conquer) are exactly the same thing/exactly the same problem solving approach or at least different terms **for the same thing/topic**.

Am I misunderstanding something? If yes what is the difference I am overlooking? If not why are they treated as different things in texts?

Answer (score 3):

They are somewhat related concepts, but not the same. Induction is a way of proving something by building up from smaller cases. "Divide and conquer" is an approach to solving a problem (which may be a proof).

Not all induction problems can be described as divide and conquer. For example, there are any number of arithmetic statements like $\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}2$ that can be proved by induction, but these proofs wouldn't be considered divide and conquer since you're just incrementally adding one more element at a time. Usually, "divide and conquer" suggests splitting up the problem into chunks (e.g., halves or thirds).

On the other hand, not all divide and conquer approaches are instances of induction. Maybe you're trying to find a path visiting different delivery locations in a city (the Travelling Salesman Problem): you might break this down into neighbourhoods, then break it down again as needed, solve the smaller problems, then recombine them. But the result will not necessarily be optimal, and notably this wasn't part of a proof, just an approach to a problem.

Comment: From your second paragraph I got the impression that "divide and conquer" is a subset of induction. Induction in general is defined as composition of smaller instances which can be from $n$ to $n + 1$ while for "divide and conquer" the smaller instances are specific fractions of the original instance e.g. 50% or 33%. Does that make sense?
In regards to the 3rd paragraph, I didn't understand the meaning of it. How is the fact that the divide and conquer approach to TSP is suboptimal related to if the d&c is instance of induction? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Jim Right, that makes sense. In the context of inductive proofs, divide and conquer is one approach (but not the only one), indeed making it a subset. As for the final paragraph, I was aiming to show that it turns up not just in proofs but also in other contexts, e.g., heuristics; see the links provided by JG in their answer. The reason I brought up (sub-)optimality of the TSP was to show that the point wasn't about a proof but just getting some approximation.

Comment: @Jim That being said, suppose that you wanted to show that the resulting path was valid for the TSP (regardless of whether it was optimal or not), i.e., that it was connected and didn't have any loops, etc. In that case, it would be appropriate to use divide and conquer for an inductive proof.

Answer (score 1):

They're related, but different. When you prove, by induction on $n$, the complexity (be it in time or memory) of a recursive algorithm for solving a size-$n$ problem, divide and conquer as a definition of that recursive algorithm proves a recurrence relation used in the inductive step.

For example, [this algorithm for the tower of Hanoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Recursive_solution) takes $T_n$ movements with $n$ discs with $T_0=0$, and divide and conquer proves $T_{k+1}=2T_k+1$, allowing us to prove by induction $T_n=2^n-1$.

Note that divide and conquer can also be used to prove approximations, asymptotic behaviours, and bounds for the complexity; see [here](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Evazirani/algorithms/chap2.pdf) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)#Generic_form).

Comment: In the tower of Hanoi the problem for $n$ disks is solved using the solution of moving $n - 1$ disks from one peg to another. So it seems to me an instance of induction since the solution is based on having the solutions of smaller instances of the problem. The divide and conquer part seems to only refer to the fact that we are calling the sub solutions for different pegs i.e. 2 times. I don't see any mention of divide and conquer term in the wiki you have linked to or may be I am confused

Comment: @Jim D&C comes up in the algorithm for moving the pegs; the fact that the algorithm works that way lets us prove by induction how many moves it uses.